# str_replace with variable generated string not working with php

Tags: php, str-replace

I am sure this has something to do with using variables to populate a string, but I am not sure how to fix the problem.

I have a sql statement that gets populated through variable which may or may not contain data which is why I have to do it this way.

Example

```
if ($data1 != '') {
    $col1 = "col1 = '".$data1."', "
}
if ($data2 != '') {
    $col2 = "col2 = '".$data2."', "
}
if ($data3 != '') {
    $col3 = "col3 = '".$data3."', "
}
```

Not every `$data` may contain something so some variables will be empty and not part of my SQL statement, but lets assume all three have data.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET $col1$col2$col3 WHERE ID = '$ID'";
```

which then produces

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET col1 = 'data1', col2 = 'data2', col3 = 'data3', WHERE ID = '$ID'";
```

The problem is the last comma in the sql statement before the `, WHERE`. That needs to be removed.

So I tried

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET $col1$col2$col3 WHERE ID = '$ID'";
$sql = str_replace(", WHERE", " WHERE", $sql);
```

but that seems to be ignoring it. I thought maybe I needed to do something like `strval($sql)` first, but again didn't work.

Is there a way to get this to work? Am I making this harder than I need too?

Comment: because `$col3` may not always be the last variable in the statement. Remember if the data is blank it will have an empty variable so it will not appear. I cant determine which variable will always be last which is why I have to have a comma at the end of each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if ($data1 != '') {
    $col1 = "col1 = '".$data1."', "
}
if ($data2 != '') {
    $col2 = "col2 = '".$data2."', "
}
if ($data3 != '') {
    $col3 = "col3 = '".$data3."', "
}
```

use something like:

```
$update_arr = array();
if ($data1 != '') {
    $update_arr[] = "col1 = '".$data1."'";
}
if ($data2 != '') {
    $update_arr[] = "col2 = '".$data2."'";
}
if ($data3 != '') {
    $update_arr[] = "col3 = '".$data3."'";
}
```

and then create update part of query like this:

```
if ($update_arr) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET ".implode(", ", $update_arr)." WHERE ID = '$ID'";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the last comma using [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) doing something like this:

```
$columns = null;
if ($data1 != '') {
  $columns = "col1 = '$data1', ";
}
if ($data2 != '') {
  $columns .= "col2 = '$data2', ";
}
if ($data3 != '') {
  $columns .= "col3 = '$data3', ";
}

if ($columns) {
  // remove any trailing ','
  $columns = rtrim($columns, ',');

  $sql = "UPDATE table SET $columns WHERE ID = '$ID'";
}
```